# Producing a linear distribution for a "donut" shape

Tags: r, random, statistics, probability

I am trying to produce a distribution for points within a circle where there are more towards the center, but for a donut shape

I can produce a uniformly distributed donut shape (1), or a circle where there are more points towards the center (2) but not a donut shape that has so many points towards its inside boundary.

(1)

```
r = sqrt(runif(250, min = 0.25, max =1))
p = runif(250)
theta = p *2*pi
a = r * cos(theta) #coordinates for circle
b = r * sin(theta)
plot(a,b)
```

(2)

```
r = runif(250)
p = runif(250)
theta = p *2*pi
a = r * cos(theta)
b = r * sin(theta)
plot(a,b)
```

My closest attempt is modifying program (2) where r is bound between 0.5 and 1 but this removes most of the points closest to the center and does not have as many around its inside.

Comment: No, not at all.

Comment: Try generating r and theta independently, and then let your point be (r, theta), with theta having a uniform distribution over [0, 2 pi), and r having a distribution with support in [0.5, 1], with more density towards 0.5. There are many such distributions, one is a shift, truncated exponential. Try first generating from an exponential, then from a shifted exponential, and finally a truncated, shifted exponential. Good luck and have fun, seems like a good problem. PS. For fun take a look at the Wikipedia article about "Bertrand's problem".

Answer (score 5):

As @RobertDodier said, try to use some advanced distribution for radius. What I would like to propose is [Beta distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution).

First, it is naturally in the [0...1] range, no need to truncate, accept/reject etc.
Second, it has two parameters (a,b) which could be used to get single peak, zero at 0, and slope to 1. Look at graphs in the wiki page. And last, it is implemented in **R**. `a` being smaller than `b` means peak is on the lef of 0.5, `a` being larger than `b` means peak is on the right of 0.5.

Along the lines

```
N = 10000
r = rbeta(N, 7.0, 5.0)
theta = 2.0*pi*runif(N)
a = r * cos(theta)
b = r * sin(theta)
plot(a,b)
```

will produce plot like that

[image]

Does it look like at donut?

UPDATE

This one is with clear hole at the center and shape proposed by  @RobertDodier

```
N = 10000
hole = 0.25
r = hole + (1.0-hole)*rbeta(N, 1.0, 3.0)
theta = 2.0*pi*runif(N)
a = r * cos(theta)
b = r * sin(theta)
plot(a,b)
```

[image]

Another one with clear hole in the center and symmetric shape, like a true donut

```
r = hole + (1.0-hole)*rbeta(N, 2.0, 2.0)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for working out an example. OP writes "more towards the center", which is a little ambiguous, but perhaps something like `r = 1 + rbeta(N, 1.0, 3.0)` ? I guess at this point we need OP to steer us in the right direction.

Comment: @RobertDodier thanks for reminding that OP wanted some clear hole (0.25? 0.5?) in the center, I've updated the answer with couple of examples including shape proposed by you. Let's wait for OP to provide feedback.